# How to update the order with data sent from axios?

Tags: json, laravel

hi i want to update one of my tables with the new data i post to my controller is there a way to do some thing like

```
Platform::update($request->all());
```

my post request is like this

```
  axios.post(`http://www.crown.mehi/admin/platforms`, { data })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
```

i changed the data inside of json request and i want to update my table in database with it

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    dd($request->all);
   Platform::update($request->all());
}
```

here is the data

```
0: {id: 2, order: 0, name: "Google DCM", slug: null, layout: {…}, …}
1: {id: 3, order: 1, name: "Google Ads", slug: null, layout: {…}, …}
2: {id: 6, order: 2, name: "TubeMogulll", slug: null, layout: null, …}
3: {id: 4, order: 3, name: "TubeMogul", slug: null, layout: {…}, …}
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: yes it's possible... just make `dd($request->all())` on first line inside controller function and see what you get there through browser (Chrome or Firefox whatever you use) under Network tab (Developer tools). I hope you can follow all this.
That console.log(res) is giving the response after that controller function is finished!

Comment: @lewis4u  ty for your time i get this error {status of 422 (unprocessable entity)}

Comment: That means your validation fails... Do you have a Request class for that or you validate inside controller?

Comment: @lewis4u i dont have Request class i use the default store method in the controller

Comment: OK... can you post that inside your question. That store method.

Comment: @lewis4u i fixed that problem i get a 500 error from server now when trying the update and nothing for dd($request->all()) at network tab

Comment: When you get error 500 then always check your laravel.log files and/or server log files... there is the exact message what happened. Server log files depend on what are you using, Linux, Mac, Windows? Homestead? XAMPP? So what is your setup?

Comment: @lewis4u ye ty u i found this in log Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] so we cant use it like that

Comment: Yes... you can't say Platform::update() It doesn't know which record you want to update. You need to send it through in that request then you could do `Platform::find($id)->update($request->all());`

Comment: @lewis4u yeah thats the problem all of my data rows in that json file and i want to update them all in table not just find one and update it

Comment: Can you make some dummy example of that json data in your question just so we can see the structure. I mean that what gets dumped in controller `$request->all()` it should be something like `['data' => '{"key": "value"...}']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215816/discussion-between-mehran-and-lewis4u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution for the problem was this:

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request['data'] as $entry) {
        Platform::where('id', $entry['id'])->update(['order' => $entry['order']]);
    }
}
```

You have to go through all of the sent items and update them.

Comment: ty for the help